# Android - Can't compile on JRE - Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I want to compile my app from command line, and not from Android Studio.
My app works perfectly when I launch it from Android Studio to my device / emulator, however when I try to do :

```
gradlew build
```

I get :

```
> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsReleaseKotlin FAILED
Caught an exception trying to connect to Kotlin Daemon
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_191' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.JarSearchingUtilKt.findToolsJar(jarSearchingUtil.kt:95)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerEnvironment$toolsJar$2.invoke(GradleCompilerEnvironment.kt:23)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerEnvironment$toolsJar$2.invoke(GradleCompilerEnvironment.kt:17)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:131)
        ...
```

Here is my JAVA_HOME env var :

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_191
```

It IS actually a JRE (and not a JDK), but, when I change my env var by my JDK as following :

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1
```

And I launch :

```
gradlew build
```

Then I get :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: I've found that Android can't build with JDK 11. It works fine with 8 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably complaining about the fact you are trying to use a JDK 11 version when your gradle is only compatible up to a lesser JDK version.

The short answer would be - download a JDK 1.8.something version and try with that, the alternate (and probably better long term) answer would be to upgrade your gradle version to the latest (i.e. a JDK 11 compatible version).

EDIT: so google says that you need a minimum of Gradle 5.0 to use JDK 11 :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to use JDK 8, but you are using JDK 11.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac M1 chip users, add the following line in **gradle.properties**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home
```

you can find your java home path

> AndroidStudio -> File -> ProjectStructure -> SDKs -> Android studio
> java home

[image: Java Home Path]

Answer (score 0):

In `gradle-wrapper.properties` add the following line

```
org.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

Replace with the path to your JDK

I used to build integration_test for flutter

Answer (score -1):

*This worked for me*

1. Download **Gradle** from [gradle.org](https://gradle.org/) **OR** from [services.gradle.org](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-bin.zip)
2. Unzip the downloaded file in `C://`
3. Update the /bin path in `System Environment Variables`
   *Run the program and check if the problem is fixed? Proceed next if you still got the error(s)*
4. Download **Java SE Runtime Environment 8u261** [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jre8-downloads.html)
5. Update the /bin path in `System Environment Variables`
   *This will fix the issue. Lemme know if you still got errors*

Comment: using [solved] in bold is not how stackoverflow does things. Could you update it to say this worked for you?

Answer (score -2):

In my case, `java` and `javac` had different versions. Check out and configure with:

```
 $ update-alternatives --config javac
```

and

```
 $ update-alternatives --config java
```

This [article](https://www.geofis.org/en/install/install-on-linux/install-openjdk-8-on-ubuntu-trusty/) helped a lot. I see this article is for Windows, but somebody using Ubuntu may find this answer useful.